# Suggestions on learning new languages allowed here?

Tags: discussion

I know C++, Python, JavaScript and Prolog.

I want to learn Java.

Will my question be deleted if I ask for recommendations on StackOverflow?

If so, is there another StackExchange site I can ask on?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to learn Java, then start with a nice tutorial on Java. Don't ask for recommendations. That's not what we're here for.

Instead, dig into that tutorial, get your hands dirty, and get stuck in the mud. Once you're stuck, you'll actually be able to relate to a specific problem you're facing, and you'll be able to ask a well researched question, despite it being a beginner question.

When you ask questions that you've put effort into, you'll find that the answers you get are much more meaningful. You'll actually be able to understand what the answerers are saying to you, instead of then spamming each party with "What do you mean, can you tell me more about X?"

What's more, this is your way of giving back to the community. If you ask well-researched questions about a problem you're facing, there's a good chance someone else is facing that same problem! In short, by helping us help you, you also help others in the process, and that's awesome!

In short, recommendation questions would be quickly closed as having little value to future visitors. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm looking for that "nice tutorial on Java"!

Comment: If you can't find a good tutorial using Google, you're really going to struggle as a programmer. Everyday there's something new that I have to Google and learn on my own. Consider that this question and those like them have already been asked and answered countless times on the Internet. Part of being a programmer is learning to differentiate poor material from good material. So, give it a shot, check out Oracle, the maintainers of Java, to start, and then go from there. When you get stuck, please do come back to Stack Overflow and we'd be happy to help. :)

Comment: I hope it's clear that my comment isn't intended as disrespect, just helpful advice. We all were once new and had to learn when to ask questions and when to just dig in on our own. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Yeah yeah, happy to learn languages on my own without any recommendations; that's what I did with C++. But then on ##C++ on Freenode one day I was recommended a really good C++ book that made the other book next-to worthless. So I would like to reduce time wasted as much as possible, and I'm sure others would appreciate time saved also.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser95 You could try asking in an appropriate SO chatroom whether one of the inhabitants is willing to recommend a good resource.

Answer (score 4):

There really isn't a site that this would belong on, since it's too inspecific.  Some open-ended questions that I can think of:

- What level of programming would you be doing with the new language?
- What can't you do in [insert known languages here] that you can't do with Java?

There's also the issue of requesting books, tutorials, and the like, all of which are too subjective to be pinned down to one thing.

Don't get me wrong, I totally admire that you want to learn Java, and I would strongly suggest that you read [the Java tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info) to get your feet wet.  Asking that sort of question on SO would be a quick candidate for closure due to "Not a Real Question".

Comment: So if I write up a more specific question including some of the frameworks I'll be using, the architecture (e.g.: SOA) and the version of Java will it then not get deleted?

Comment: Depends.  If it's a specific question concerning a specific problem, then it would stick around.